# BlockingCollection multiple thread Producer Consumer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, producer-consumer

i want to implement multiple thread Producer Consumer, my purpose is insert strings into my `Queue`, each string represent `DOC file` that need to be check (simple search inside the document) and in this check is OK the doc file can be add into my `ListView`.

```
public class ProducerConsumer
{
    public delegate void OnFileAddDelegate(string file);
    public event OnFileAddDelegate OnFileAddEventHandler;
    private BlockingCollection<string> queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    public void Start(int workerCount)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (count < workerCount)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(StartConsuming);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
            count++;
        }
    }

    public void Produce(string item)
    {
        queue.Add(item);
    }

    private void StartConsuming()
    {
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            string item = queue.Take();

            // Check my file
            FileChecker fileChecker = new FileChecker();
            string result = fileChecker.Check(item); 

            // If the file is OK fire up an event to my main form to add this file
            if (result != null && OnFileAddEventHandler != null)
                OnFileAddEventHandler(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want add to my class the option to add files in multiple thread.
Any suggestions how to do that ?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem or what the question is?

Comment: Is my Consumer is multiple thread ?

Comment: If you ask multiple threads are processing the work items(consumers) **no**, you have only one consumer created in `Start` method. Of course **yes** if you call `Start` method multiple times.

Comment: What i need to change in order to support multiple threads ? i don't think call Start multiple times is a good idea (correct me if i wrong)

Comment: Calling start multiple times is worst idea. But you could add parameter to `Start` method lets say `public void Start(int workerCount)` then start that many number of threads inside `Start` method. You're done.

Comment: Please see my update, that's what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you have used `for` loop it would be better. but that's fine. Now you can start multiple consumers. Also see [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx), In that page search for `PCQueue`. You'll find a better implementation of producer consumer.